# Memory layout of VK_FORMAT_G8_B8_R8_3PLANE_420_UNORM

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to figure out which memory layout `VK_FORMAT_G8_B8_R8_3PLANE_420_UNORM` has in Vulkan.
What I think I understand:

- each component has **8**bits
- the normalized unsigned value for each component is then **0-255**

So I would have expected components to be something like `G0G1B0R0G2G3B2R2`.

Which would satisfy **4:2:0**:

- offset of **4**
- **2** values for first line  at least for `G`. Though not for `B` and `R`.

Getting RGB, planes and 420 combined seems too much for my brain.

Could someone explain how this is supposed to be interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is multi-plane image, so basically each component is its own separate image (resp. aspect).

The G plane is image size. The B and R planes are each half width and height.

Comment: So in other words memory layout would be `G0G1G2G3B0B2R0R2`?

Comment: @abergmeier I don't know what you mean. If it is multiplane format then the components are not interleaved at all. It would be just GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG in aspect 0. BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB in aspect 1, and RRRRRRRRRRRRRRR in aspect 2. Only aspect 1 and aspect 2 would have half the image dimensions of aspect 0.

Comment: Note that the main purpose of this format is for sampling from YUV 420 video surfaces sourced from video codec hardware (or software), so the data in memory probably isn't actually RGB at all. The conversion is handled in the sampler.